# Why does frame selection breaks after page reloads?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to inspect a page with playwright that holds a frame document that when I click a button a banner will appear for a couple of minutes. When it's done the page needs to be reloaded for the banner to disappear. I am checking every 5 minutes automatically until I don't see the banner on the page but when I can only do it for the 1 loop after that the code breaks. What can I do to fix this.

A possible solution could be going to the iframe link itself but the document breaks if I do that. I wish to avoid doing this. It's not how I would do things if I was manually doing this.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: frame.evaluate: Execution Context is not available in detached frame (are you trying to evaluate?)

```
const browser = await chromium.launch({ 
    args: ["--start-maximized", "--disable-notifications",  '--disable-extensions', '--mute-audio'],
    defaultViewport: null,
    devtools: true,
    slowMo: 50,
    downloadsPath: "D:\\Lambda\\projects\\puppeteer_test\\data",
});

// Create a new incognito browser context with user credentials
const context = await browser.newContext({
    acceptDownloads: true,
    viewport: null,
    storageState: JSON.parse(storageState),
})

// Create a new page in a pristine context. 
const page = await context.newPage()

// go to download your information
await page.goto("");

//select child frame
const frameDocUrl = await (await page.waitForSelector("iframe")).getAttribute("src")
const doc = await page.frame({url: frameDocUrl})
await doc.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');

/* waitForFile */
// refresh every 5 minute until notice of gathering file is gone 
// then Pending becomes download
const frameUrl = await doc.url()
const fiveMinutes = 300000
let IsGatheringFile = await doc.$("//div[text()='A copy of your information is being created.']") ? true: false
while(IsGatheringFile){
    //reload page
    console.log("going to reload")
    await doc.goto(frameUrl)
    
    // wait for 5 minutes
    console.log(`going to start waiting for 5 min starting in ${Date().split(" ")[4]}`)
    await doc.waitForTimeout(fiveMinutes)
    console.log("finish reloading")

    // check if notice is gone
    IsGatheringFile = await doc.$("//div[text()='A copy of your information is being created.']") ? true: false
}
console.log("finish waiting for data")

console.log("finish reloading the page until the banner is gone")
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
after the page refresh/new navigation recapture the focus on the iframe.

```
const frameUrl = await doc.url()
await doc.goto(frameUrl)
```

Also, note that you can update the variable that you are passing by to the other parts of your script with the new refresh iframe.

old hacky fix:

Instead of reloading the page reload the iframe.

At the moment there is no frame.reload but this process can be achieved by frame.goto(frameURL)

```
const frameUrl = await doc.url()
await doc.goto(frameUrl)
```

Note: iframe can break. Reloading the page can fix it but the frame will be detached.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old but I will respond anyway as I had this problem this week and just resolved it.

I am in python not Node, but the logic is still the same I believe.

So for me, just recapturing the focus didn't work after the page.reload().

I did use the "old hacky fix" and instead of reload all the page, reloaded just the frame concerned.
My solution is like that :

```
iframe.goto(iframe.url)
is_detached = iframe.is_detached()

if is_detached:
    iframe = page.main_frame.child_frames[-1]
```